# Bootstrap icon is not displaying

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

This is my code. I wanted to add Date Icon but its not displaying . Its displaying some kind of default icon , something like rectangle with text EIo9 .I'm using latest bootstrap link

Comment: Where is your code? It seems that font file is not loaded perfectly? are your using CDN or picking the file locally?

Comment: If you go into the developer console, are there any errors?

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:59197/Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
glyphic...ar.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:59197/Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding this link to your page then, it should work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your assets directory location are correct? like `css`,`images` and `fonts` i.e.

Answer (score 0):

**All you need is bootstrap css file getting included in a right way.**

You can take it from localhost or [CDN](http://bootstrapcdn.com/) so the code will be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

[Here's the working example](http://jsbin.com/movene/1/). Good luck!